# SumIfs Formula Issue

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a monthly spreadsheet that has a link taking you to another spreadsheet with totals, could be one total by vendor, could be several according to the month.  Constantly changes.  I want to be able to bring those totals to the Summary spreadsheet and sum each month by vendor but it is a manual process since lines per Vendor change each month.

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(D4:E9,MATCH(G4,C4:C9,0),MATCH(G5,D3:E3,0)))
```

THIS IS TELLING ME I HAVE ENTERED TOO FEW ARGUMENTS

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(D4:E9,MATCH(G4,C4:C9,0),MATCH(G5,D3:E3,0)))
```

DOES NOT WORK...TOO FEW ARGUMENTS??

Comment: `SUMIFS` requires a summing range, criteria range, and criteria -- at minimum

Comment: Can you explain a bit further since I have never used Sumifs,

Comment: (I updated your title to reflect the formula that's giving the issue, if I understand correctly. Feel free to revert it back if that's incorrect).  Also see [SUMIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b).

Comment: So if the Summing Range is D4:E9 - Index, I would think the Criteria range would be the match or C4:C9 and criteria G4, and again Criteria range D3:E3 with criteria G5.  Am I thinking this wrong?

Comment: The SumIfs Formula Issue is exactly what it is, Thank You

Comment: Why are you wrapping a standard index/match/match in a sumifs?  Your Index/match/match will return a single cell's value from the range D4:E9.  You're not actually summing anything.  And because you're only returning a single cell, Sumifs is complaining that you have too few arguments (you've only provided a single argument, so sumifs cannot compute properly).  This question would greatly benefit from sample data and expected results so we can get a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish, but at first glace it looks like you just need to remove the Sumifs function entirely.